# How many concurrent requests can i send to cognito Access token endpoint - POST /oauth2/token

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-cognito

I am encountering an error with cognito: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$TooManyRequests: ***429 Too Many Requests***

I believe this is happening when the application is sending too many requests to Cognito. Therefore wanted to know, what is the max concurrent limit Cognito can handle?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html see soft limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current soft max is 10 requests/second. But usually AWS can go up to 40 without a design level check. Anything higher needs a review from Cognito development team